# How to call delete function in sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to use below given delete function from my Database Handler file. When I am implementing it javaNullpointerException is coming. I am definitely missing something.

**Delete Function:**

```
// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}
```

**I am trying to use as:**

```
     DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
Contact pm = null;
Intent i;
i = getIntent();
pm._id= i.getExtras().getInt("id");
pm._name = i.getExtras().getString("name");
pm._phone_number = i.getExtras().getString("phone_number");

        // **Some problem is here I am not getting it

                        db.deleteContact(pm);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Deleted..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
08-19 01:15:00.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12657): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 01:15:00.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12657): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-19 01:15:00.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12657):    at com.parth.targetthebudget.ViewContact$ListAdapter$2$1.onClick(ViewContact.java:151)
08-19 01:15:00.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12657):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:163)
08-19 01:15:00.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12657):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 01:15:00.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12657):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-19 01:15:00.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12657):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-19 01:15:00.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12657):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 01:15:00.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12657):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-19 01:15:00.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12657):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-19 01:15:00.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12657):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-19 01:15:00.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12657):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from what i understand you are trying to send data from 1 activity to another so you can delete the record that matches data?

you have Contact pm = null;
then you are trying to get the id of a null record in the database.
im sure your following this
 http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ 
remove

```
Contact pm = null;
pm._id= i.getExtras().getInt("id");
pm._name = i.getExtras().getString("name");
pm._phone_number = i.getExtras().getString("phone_number");
```

add

```
Contact pm = db.getContact(i.getExtras().getInt("id"));
```

that will remove the record that has the same id from what you sent in the intent

Comment: Yes, I had already tried this but the problem is that if I had given ID = 1 then logcat is showing 08-19 01:40:20.351: E/AndroidRuntime(13678): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
that means its not deleting the data of ID = 1 !!!

Comment: Are you sure that there is a record with id of 1?